# HTML 5 Hex String for Pattern Attribute

Tags: regex, html, validation, hex

I have several form elements that accept hex strings like the one shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="..." onkeyup="a('...')" pattern=\"[a-fA-F0-9]+\" value=\"****\"/>
```

I am interested in shorting the pattern attribute value to something shorter, but still accept the same pattern.  I am doing this because this html is embedded in a micro controller and saving space is desirable.  Is there a predefined cross browser hex matching class?

Comment: You mean a shorter pattern string than `[a-fA-F0-9]+`? I think it is not possible in such context, primarily because of the forced case sensitivity. :/

Answer (score 8):

Only thing shorter is

```
<input pattern="[a-fA-F\d]+"/>
```

The `\d` character class is equivalent to `0-9`.

More info: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)