# C# ASP MVC - A field that only accepts hexadecimal values for colors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, colors, hex

I'm making an admin input panel.

Admin will have an option to create a custom color using an hexadecimal value such as #0000ff or #008000, etc.

Right now, I´m using this in my model:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter the color")]
public string Color { get; set; }
```

How can I validate so the admin can only put hexadecimal values here?

And most importantly, is this really necessary? I heard that the browser tends to ignore false hex codes [Why does HTML think “chucknorris” is a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)

Comment: You write javascript that validates the input.  There is no one way to do it.  Try it out and if something goes wrong, [edit] your question to add a JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet with details about why it isn't working.

Comment: See this but note it requires browser support, and note this is client side only, it doesn't have anything to do with validating server side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414348/html-5-hex-string-for-pattern-attribute

Comment: You could use an existing javascript based control with browser side validation. [There are enough out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+color+picker+control).

Comment: I don't see why someone would vote this questions as "Too Broad".  It's about as specific as a question about validation can get.

Comment: I see, so I need to do this via javascript. I though there was a way to do it server side =/

Comment: You validate both sides. But the client-side makes for a better user experience.

Comment: Yeah, everything in my app has both validations, but I am not understanding how to validate this on the server side too.

Comment: For server side validation you can do a TryParse or use a RegEx. There are existing answers out there like this one on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25933687/1260204

Comment: Another client-side option is simply `<input type="color">`. Of course that only works with HTML5 compliant browsers, so you'll need a fallback, but it's definitely the best way to go for modern browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that it is beter to validate your inputs then relay on custom behaviour of browsers.

You can validate your field more or less with following attribute:

```
public class HexColorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string _errorMessage;

    public HexColorAttribute(string errorMessage)
    {
        _errorMessage = errorMessage
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var colorHexStr = (string)value;
        var valid = Regex.IsMatch(colorHexStr, "#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}");
        if(valid)
        {
              return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
              return new ValidationResult(_errorMessage)
        }

    }
```

and then:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter the color")]
[HexColor("Color has to have format '#123456'")]
public string Color { get; set; }
```

It is working similarly to Required attribiute. Take a look at [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RequiredAttribute.cs) of RequiredAttribute.

Comment: "then relay on custom behaviour of browsers."  This is the one statement I have serious issue with, because you don't need to rely on custom behavior.  You can implement client side validation using features defined in non-browser specific standards:  https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute 
For browsers not supporting the standard, usually poly-fills bring the browser inline with the standard.  Obviously you should always have server side validation, but one does not preclude the benefit of the other.